# How do I draw a circle looping around with a circle in the middle at the end using python turtle?

Tags: python, loops, geometry, turtle-graphics

The shape should look like this image 
[Image of Circle Loop](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall13/CSCI-UA.0002-005/assignments/turtle-graphics/circles.png)

This should be a simple hw assignment, so if you are using any advanced math or anything you're probably not doing it correctly. It should only involve simple functions like left, right, forward, penup, pendown, etc.

I really need help finishing this. This is the code I have down so far, but the circle is not moving correctly.

```
# Repeating Circle Loop

import turtle

turtle.colormode(255)

window = turtle.Screen()
window.title('Circle Loop')
window.bgcolor('black')

red, green, blue = 255, 255, 0

draw = turtle.Turtle()
draw.color(red, green, blue)

radius = 50

for i in range(12):
    draw.circle(radius)
    draw.penup()
    draw.setposition(i * - 10, 0)
    draw.left(30)
    draw.pendown()
    green = green - 20
    blue = blue + 20
    draw.color(red, green, blue)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Telling people that "This should be a simple hw assignment, so if you guys are using any advanced math or anything you're probably not doing it correctly.", doesn't invite anybody to actually answer.

Answer (score 1):

Write a subroutine to draw a circle. Then, write another subroutine that draws a circle, curving in the opposite direction, and calls the first subroutine to draw additional circles around the inner circle at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in some code like this:

```
from math import sin, cos, pi
from turtle import *

tracer(2,1)

def myCircle(x, y, r, c1, c2): # draw a circle with radius r in the point (x,y)
            up(); goto(x+r, y) ; down()
            color(c1, c2)
            begin_fill()
            for i in range(361):
                a = x + r*cos(pi*i/180)
                b = y + r*sin(pi*i/180)
                goto(a, b)
            end_fill()

c1, c2 = 'red', 'blue'
for i in range(5):
    myCircle(0, 0, 200-i*40,c1, c2 )
    c1, c2 = c2, c1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this loop:

```
for i in range(12):
    draw.circle(radius)
    draw.penup()
    draw.left(180)
    draw.circle(radius,30)
    draw.right(180)
    draw.pendown()
```